# Create a baseball standings table

Tags: array, plugin-supersort

I am building a baseball standings table.
I currently have a Single section setup in Craft to handle some basic info.
It contains a table field with 3 rows: Team, Wins and Losses.

I am able to output this info via the following code:

```
{% for records in standings %}
    {% for row in records.southStandings %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.team }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.wins }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.losses }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ row.wins + row.losses }}</td>
            <td>{{ (row.wins / (row.wins + row.losses))|round(3, 'common') }}</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[image: standings table]

However I am needing to do a few things for these standings.

1. Needing to sort the teams via their winning percentage (W%), if W% is same then alphabetically.

The W% is calculated this way:
`{% set wP = (team.wins / (team.wins + team.losses))|round(3, 'common') %}`

2. Calculate the games behind (GB).

Games behind is another equation, like so:
`{% set gamesBackA = ((teamA.wins - teamB.wins) + (teamB.losses - teamA.losses)) / 2 %}`

GB is how far back teams are from the leading team (1st place).

I am not even sure how I would set this and output the correct number at all, so any guidance on this would be wonderful.

I have tried setting an new empty array before my for loop and setting it within the loop. But the only way it outputs more than won W% number in that array is another for loop, like so:

```
{% set standings = craft.entries.section('standings') %}
{% set wPArray = [] %}

{% for teams in standings %}
    {% for team in teams.southStandings %}
        {% set wP = (team.wins / (team.wins + team.losses))|round(3, 'common') %}
        {% set wPArray = wPArray|merge([wP]) %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

{% for t in wPArray %}
    {{ t }}
{% endfor %}
```

I can then sort using SuperSort but that doesn't allow me to output the Team, Wins, Losses, Games Played (GP), and Games Back.

What am I missing with the arrays?

What is the best approach to output the table, sort them by W%/alphabetically and calculate Games Back as well.

I do have the SuperSort plugin installed.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!